# How to create a TRUE Python program

Tags: python, user-interface, compilation

So I have been studying Python for some time now, learned all the foundations.

With this knowledge I decided to create a project, right now I have written some code and some functionality, but everything is done by the terminal.

Does anybody know where I can find the resources to learn how to  create a fully fleshed-out Python program? I want to convert the script to a true .exe, with a GUI , inputs outside the terminal, etc…

If anyone is interested here is the basic program: GitHub - pedrodeoliamarante/roadto10k. There isn’t much yet but the idea is to create a program where I can save data on what i have been studying, set goals, etc…

Thanks for reading!

Comment: I don't agree that you've described a "true" or "full" Python program. Plenty of those don't have GUIs and aren't packaged into exe files. But if you are interested in those things, that's cool. People seem to like tkinter and py2exe for that stuff.

Comment: This needs decisions first for a GUI toolkit (e. g. tkinter, wxPython, PyQt) and an exe packer like e. g. py2exe. The GUI decision is much more important as it affects the actual program code.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at QT for Python.

https://www.qt.io/qt-for-python

I think this is what you are looking for.